# How to use plural Page-Object widgets

Tags: ruby, page-object-gem

I'm using the "[PageObject](https://github.com/cheezy/page-object)" gem and Ruby and created a widget using the "[page-object wiki](https://github.com/cheezy/page-object/wiki/Custom-page-object-elements-by-using-widgets)" as a reference.

I cannot find plural elements, meaning I can't find an array of elements.

If the tag for my widget is `some-widget`, this works:

```
some_widget_element(id: 'some-id')
```

But this does NOT work:

```
some_widget_elements(id: 'some-id')
```

I am trying to find multiple elements by id, which is how the page is structured.

I get the error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method 'new' for nil:NilClass
```

Is there anything I need to do/add to my Widget class?

Comment: See "[Don’t use “click here” and other common hyperlink mistakes](https://medium.com/@heyoka/dont-use-click-here-f32f445d1021)".

Comment: Is this with using the accessor or the nested element call? As far as I know, both should work as you expected.

Comment: @Justin Ko, it is with both. I cannot do it as shown in OP and also if I were to do, for example, `div_elements[1].some_widget_element`.

Answer (score 0):

Registering a widget will define both:

- The page-level accessor as well as
- The nested element locator

As an example, let's assume the following HTML:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div>empty</div>
    <div>
      <some-widget id="some-id">a</some-widget>
      <some-widget id="some-id">b</some-widget>
      <other id="some-id">c</other>
    </div>
    <some-widget id="some-id">d</some-widget>
  </body>
</html>
```

As well, that we have registered the widget:

```
class SomeWidgetClass < PageObject::Elements::Element
  PageObject.register_widget :some_widget, self, :element
end
```

**Nested Element**

The created nested element method is in the form "{widget_tag}_elements".

```
class TestPage
  include PageObject

  def nested_in_page
    some_widget_elements(id: 'some-id', tag_name: 'some-widget')
  end

  def nested_in_element
    div_elements[1].some_widget_elements(id: 'some-id', tag_name: 'some-widget')
  end
end

page = TestPage.new(browser)
p page.nested_in_page.map(&:text)
#=> ["a", "b", "d"]
p page.nested_in_element.map(&:text)
#=> ["a", "b"]
```

**Page-Level Accessor**

By default, the page-level accessor for returning an Array of all matching widgets is based on the widget's class name. This differs from the singular accessor method, which you define when registering the widget. Specifically, the method name is defined by the following expression:

```
def self.plural_form
  "#{self.to_s.split('::')[-1].
      gsub(/([A-Z]+)([A-Z][a-z])/, '\1_\2').
      gsub(/([a-z\d])([A-Z])/, '\1_\2').
      tr("-", "_").
      downcase}s"
end
```

In our example, the `SomeWidgetClass` class would create a `some_widget_classs` method:

```
class TestPage
  include PageObject

  some_widget_classs(:my_widgets, id: 'some-id', tag_name: 'some-widget')
end

page = TestPage.new(browser)
p page.my_widgets_elements.map(&:text)
#=> ["a", "b", "d"]
```

You can override the accessor name by defining the `plural_form` for your widget. The following renames the method to `plural_widgets`:

```
class SomeWidgetClass < PageObject::Elements::Element
  def self.plural_form
    :plural_widgets
  end

  PageObject.register_widget :some_widget, self, :element
end

class TestPage
  include PageObject

  plural_widgets(:my_widgets, id: 'some-id', tag_name: 'some-widget')
end
```

The actual usage of the page does not change - ie is still `page.my_widgets_elements`.